# By comparing data from different periods, how can find out which fields in the data table have changed?

Tags: postgresql

data like:

| date | code | fieldA | fieldB | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | H01 | valueA1 | valueB1 |  |
| 2023-01-10 | H01 | valueA1 | valueB1 |  |
| 2023-01-20 | H01 | valueA2 | valueB1 |  |

how to get result:
code 'H01' fieldA has changed.from '2023-01-10:valueA1' to '2023-01-20:valueA2'

how about more fileds?

I haven't found the right way yet

Answer (score 1):

You can the values for previous rows with the [lag()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) function. With that you can build result set with both current and previous rows. Then look at each specific column to detect if it changed, if so
then tag the column name along with dates and value for each date. `UNION` each the column changes. Finally build the desired output string for each. The Query does not indicate introduction of a new code as a change. If doing so is desired the remove the `p_date is not null` predicate. (See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/-82IZMd4))

```
with clist ( code
           , t_date, p_date           -- p_ ==> previous 
           , fielda, p_fielda
           , fieldb, p_fieldb
           ) as
     ( select code
            , t_date, lag(t_date) over win 
            , fieldA, lag(fieldA) over win
            , fieldB, lag(fieldB) over win
         from test
       window win as (partition by code order by t_date)  
     ) --select * from clist;
   , change_list as 
     ( select 'fieldA' fld_chg, code, t_date, p_date, fieldA val, p_fieldA p_val  
         from clist
        where p_date is not null 
          and fieldA is distinct from p_fieldA
       union all
       select 'fieldB', code, t_date, p_date, fieldB, p_fieldB 
          from clist
         where p_date is not null 
           and fieldB is distinct from p_fieldB
     ) -- select * from change_list;
select 'Code'  || '''' || code    || '''' || 
       fld_chg || ' has changed. '|| 
       'From ' || '''' || p_date::text    || ':' || coalesce(p_val,' -- ')  || '''' || 
       ' To '  || '''' || t_date::text    || ':' || coalesce(val,' -- ')    || ''''    as "Test Change Notice"
  from change_list
 order by code, t_date, fld_chg;
```

Perhaps a better option.  
SQL is a data server, and very good at it. However, it is NOT very good at formatting a presentation. So use SQL to server the data and your apps presentation manager to format the result. Something like:

```
with clist ( code
           , t_date, p_date           -- p_ ==> previous 
           , fielda, p_fielda
           , fieldb, p_fieldb
           ) as
     ( select code
            , t_date, lag(t_date) over win 
            , fieldA, lag(fieldA) over win
            , fieldB, lag(fieldB) over win
         from test
       window win as (partition by code order by t_date)  
     ) 
select * 
  from clist 
 where p_date is not null 
   and (   fieldA is distinct from p_fieldA
        or fieldB is distinct from p_fieldB
       ) 
 order by code, t_date;
```

The problem with the first query is that you need another UNION for each column. Got more columns then add more unions. Further, look at the complexity of creating the 6 column output. The second query serves up the data quite easily, got more columns, just add more OR clauses. Then let you app scan each row and generate an output for each column change.  
Caution:  
`Date` is a poor choice for a column name. It is a SQL Standard reserved word and a Postgres data type. At best using a data type as a column name causes confusion (for you not Postgres). At worst Postgres developers decide to adhere to the standard thereby breaking your  system. (Not likely, but possible).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The lag() function is a good idea. Let me try it. I have 52 fields to judge, and there may be additions or decreases in the future, so I put these 52 fields to judge in an auxiliary table. In this case, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Please post table definition (DDL) for your existing table and the mentioned auxiliary table. The solution may be vastly different depending on those definitions. Post as update to the question - **not as another comment**.